# Best way to retrieve last records values inserted into database

Tags: mysql, delphi

I'm saving a record into a customer table, and the customer table has an customer number that auto increments. I would like to know what is the best way to get that newly generated customer number directly after it was created? For example, let us say the customer table has 3 columns, ID, Name, Surname. I use the following code:

```
database.tbCustomer.Insert;
database.tbCustomerName.Value := edtName.Text;
database.tbCustomerSurname.Value := edtSurname.Text;
database.tbCustomer.Post;
```

So once I have done this, I need to get the ID that was created, as I need to use that as a FK in another table. So the easy way I suppose is to just go to the last record in the customer table, but that gives problems if more then 1 person is creating customers.

```
database.tbCustomer.Last;
```

but that approach can lead to the wrong ID being returned if more then 1 customer gets created at the same time. So how would I get the customer ID for the customer that I just created? Using Delphi, and storing the data on mysQL, using FireDAC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably what you are looking for is `GetLastAutoGenValue`. See the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDCustomConnection.GetLastAutoGenValue)

Comment: thanks will give this a try, just a question though. If another user inputs data into another table, which also has a autonumber field, if I run this function will there be a possibility that it returns that number or is the auto number being returned only one that was "created" using the database connection calling the function.

Comment: The manual documents for MySQL "in the session", which means other clients don't matter. If you used multiple threads then each should have its own connection (hence session) to the database.

Comment: No problem, the value is per connection. The other user has another executable and thus another connection.